# cross-reference prefix

Tags: latex, quarto

How to change cross-reference language in Quarto?

Take the example in docs:

```
![Elephant](elephant.png){#fig-elephant}

See @fig-elephant for an illustration.
```

In the .tex file  it is shown as `(Figure~\ref{fig-elephant})`. Rendering, result is something like `see Figure 1 for an illustration`.

How can I change `Figure` for any other word?

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fig-prefix` option to change the inline reference prefix and also `fig-title` option to change the figure caption accordingly.
See [here in Quarto Documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html#references-1) to know more options to change the reference style.

```
---
title: "Cross Reference Prefix"
format: pdf
crossref: 
  fig-prefix: "Picture"
  fig-title: "Picture"
---

## Quarto


![Elephant](elephant.png){#fig-elephant}

See @fig-elephant for an illustration.
```

---

[image: with different cross reference style]

---